# Add MPLS attributes in NETLINK Messages

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, netlink

Latest Linux Kernel 4.1.4 have MPLS data path support, We can program MPLS Routing table in kernel through NETLINK Socket. A new address family is defined AF_MPLS in socket.h.

I tried some code to write -

```
req.n.nlmsg_len = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(struct rtmsg));
req.n.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_CREATE;
req.n.nlmsg_type = RTM_NEWROUTE;
req.r.rtm_family = AF_MPLS;
req.r.rtm_table = RT_TABLE_MAIN;
req.r.rtm_protocol = RTPROT_BOOT;
req.r.rtm_scope = RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE;
req.r.rtm_type = RTN_UNICAST;
```

However I am not able to figure out how to add MPLS Label in Netlink attribute.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `net/mpls/af_mpls.c:rtm_to_route_config()`, the label should be provided with `RTA_DST` NLA.

Pls notice also assertions in the function, they're quite strict.

Comment: RTA_NEWDST and RTA_DST, both are used for labels, which one to use ?

Comment: `RTA_DST` is one incoming label to match, `RTA_NEWDST` is up to `MAX_NEW_LABELS` to push in the skb on forward (see `mpls_forward()`)

Btw, thanks for the hint, will implement it in the library now.

Comment: Not sure it will be useful to you, but thanks to your question, I started to support MPLS related RTNL in [pyroute2](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2/issues/172) . 

Now it is partly supported, but until the next week I hope to cover all what's provided by `af_mpls.c`.